# What is the difference between ";" and "GO" in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use ADO.NET as well as the sqlcmd utility to send SQL scripts to SQL Server 2008. What is the difference between using `;` and `GO` to separate chunks of SQL?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`GO` is not actually a T-SQL command. The `GO` command was introduced by Microsoft tools as a way to separate batch statements such as the end of a stored procedure. `GO` is supported by the Microsoft SQL stack tools but is not formally part of other tools.

You cannot put a `GO` into a string of SQL and send it as part of a ADO.NET command object as SQL itself does not understand the term. Another way to demonstrate this is with the profiler: set up some statements that use `GO` in Query Analyzer/Management Studio and then run the profiler when you execute. You will see they are issued as separate commands to the server.

The semi-colon is used to signify the end of a statement itself, not necessarily a whole batch.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: I started a connect to try to get GO to be a valid t-sql command: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3138257/make-go-a-first-class-language-keyword

Comment: So how are we supposed to know which statements in our SQL scripts are SQL statements and require a semicolon and which statements in our SQL scripts are not SQL statements and so don't?

Comment: New location of @EdElliott's suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32895496-make-go-a-first-class-language-keyword

Comment: legend! I was looking for that the other day.

Answer (score 52):

"GO" is similar to ; in many cases, but does in fact signify the end of a batch.

Each batch is committed when the "GO" statement is called, so if you have:

```
SELECT * FROM table-that-does-not-exist;
SELECT * FROM good-table;
```

in your batch, then the good-table select will never get called because the first select will cause an error.

If you instead had:

```
SELECT * FROM table-that-does-not-exist
GO
SELECT * FROM good-table
GO
```

The first select statement still causes an error, but since the second statement is in its own batch, it will still execute.

GO has nothing to do with committing a transaction.

Answer (score 22):

semicolon is a statement separator. The previous statement(s) is not necessarily executed when a semicolon is encountered.

```
GO
```

Signifies the end of a batch. Executes the previous batch of statements, as does encountering the end of the block.

```
GO 2
```

Means execute the batch that many times. I think I've used that option maybe twice in my life. Then again, I'm not a DBA by trade.

Answer (score 15):

1. Under SQL Server TSQL (2005 - 2016) bear in mind that:

   - Semicolon (;) is a *block* terminator.
   - GO is a *batch* terminator.
2. Additionally, GO can be used to invoke the same DML block multiple times using the following syntax:

GO [count]

Where [count] is a positive integer that indicates how many times the TSQL block of commands preceding said GO are to be carried out over and over.

3. Also, unlike semicolon, GO is **mandatory** before a new DDL, say, when you create a new view, since a semicolon separating previous commands will trigger an error. For example:

drop view #temporary_view
GO

create view #another_view...

--> NO ERRORS

If you replaced GO with a semicolon in the previous example, it will raise the following error message:

*'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.*

Comment: The most complete answer. Especially (3) is something that when overlooked will most definitely cause a script to fail.

Answer (score 4):

'GO' is typically used to indicate the end of a *batch* of SQL statements which means that you could have a `begin transaction` and `end transaction` wrapped up into a single collection of statements that could fail or succeed together.

';' is generally used to separate multiple SQL statements from one another. This is noticable in SQL scripts that need to return multiple recordsets, such as `select * from table1; select * from table2;' which would result in two separate recordsets on the client's side.

Answer (score 2):

The command GO means the end of a batch. 
Therefore all variables declared before GO are invalid after the GO command.
Against the semicolon does not end the batch.

If You will use a DML command in a procedure, use the semicolon instead GO.
For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SpMyProc
@myProcParam VARCHAR(20)
AS
DECLARE @myOtherParam INT = 5
;DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON tMyTable
UPDATE tMyTable SET myVar = @myProcParam, mySecondVar = @myOtherParam
;ENABLE TRIGGER OLL ON tMyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought the ; character separates a list of SQL commands, GO just instructs SQL Server to commit all the previous commands.