# SQL Server Stored Procedure - Return varchar id of inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on a cascading insertion where a stored procedure should return an id of the inserted row. This would not be a problem if the id of the table was an int. However, the id is a `varchar` and therefore I cannot use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

This is my procedure so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_ARTICLE
   @id varchar(50) OUTPUT, 
   @name varchar(100),
   @articleNr varchar(50),
   @gategory varchar(50),
   @containerId varchar(50),
   @contPerContainer int,
   @pictureId varchar(50) 
AS 
   SET NOCOUNT OFF

   INSERT INTO nextlabel.[Article] (name, article_nr, category, container_id, count_per_container, picture_id ) 
   VALUES (@name, @articleNr, @gategory, @containerId, @contPerContainer, @pictureId)

   SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Where the last row is not correct since the column `id` is a `varchar`.

How can I return the `id`?

Comment: Which value do you want to set to @id?

Comment: The column name is "id", in nextlabel.[Article] table, and is a varchar. It's not inserted, it's an auto generated GUID (as a varchar).

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific RDBMS you're using. Some details vary between SQL implementations, and you'll get the best answers if we know which it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NEW_ARTICLE
  @id varchar(50) OUTPUT, 
  @name varchar(100),
  @articleNr varchar(50),
  @gategory varchar(50),
  @containerId varchar(50),
  @contPerContainer int,
  @pictureId varchar(50) 
AS 
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET @id = newid()
INSERT INTO nextlabel.[Article] (id, name, article_nr, category, container_id, count_per_container, picture_id)
VALUES (@id, @name, @articleNr, @gategory, @containerId, @contPerContainer, @pictureId)

GO
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Your the man! Thanks a lot. Another question: is the GO really necessary? What does it do? (I'm new to working with procedures).

Comment: It is default batch separator set up in SSMS.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701147/in-sql-server-when-should-you-use-go-and-when-should-you-use-semi-colon and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio