# Handling batch T-SQL statements with GO commands

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Node.js app that is handling database build / versioning by reading multiple `.sql` files and executing them as transactions.

The problem I am running into is that these database build scripts require a lot of `GO` statements, as you cannot execute multiple `CREATE`s, etc. in the same context.

[However, `GO` is not T-SQL and errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) when used outside of a Microsoft application context.

Take the following shorthand:

```
CREATE database foo /* ... */
use [foo]
CREATE TABLE bar /* ... */
```

This would error if `GO` statements were not injected between each line.

I would rather not break this into multiple `.sql` files for every separate transaction - I am building a database and that would turn into hundreds of files!

I could run `String.split()` functions on all go statements and have `node` execute each as a separate transaction, but that seems very hacky.

Is there any standard or best-practice solution to this type of problem?

#### Update

[Looks like a semicolon will do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701509/1730638) for everything except `CREATE` statements on `functions`, `stored procedures`, etc. Doesn't apply to `tables` or `databases`, though which is good.

Comment: Just use the standard SQL statement termination character: `;` https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: You think this'll work? This blog post is more about CTEs and so I don't know if its totally applicable, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: All `GO` does is provide a way for the application to split the entire query into smaller queries. So using a string split is not a hack at all.

Comment: @DavidG Okay - I guess I was just worried as I would have to get smart on how to do it. For example, `GO` might not have spaces to the left or right, but you don't want to split on the string 'pogostick' either. I'd have to read line by line, parse out comments from the line, do a trim, and then check if `GO` is the only remaining characters in that line. That seems like I'm reinventing someone's wheel, but I can do it.

Comment: Well if you have control over the SQL file, you don't need to use `GO`. Instead use your own custom string, for example `###===###` or something you know will not be used elsewhere.

Comment: For those commands can be executed in same batch, you can put into a stored procedure (you can create and drop them dynamically). To create a database and go the database and do something, I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up:

1. Parsing the SQL file into an array of statements split on lines whose only content is `GO` statements & comments,
2. Creating a SQL transaction,
3. Executing all statements in the array in sequence,
4. Conditionally rolling back the entire transaction on any single statement fail,
5. Ending the transaction once all queries have completed synchronously.

A bit of work, but I think that was the best way to do it.